# PHP Filter for special characters before passing to sql database

Tags: php, mysql

How can I have my code replace the body text rather than just "returning":

```
if($body == "Garçon") 
    return;
```

Also, since == is looking for exact string of text, how do I make it look for the body containing "Garçon"?

Essentially, I'm trying to build in a filter to change "Garçon" to "Garcon" since the special "ç" character comes up "null" in my database.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to filter anything, nor replace any symbols.
Just setup your database to use utf8 encoding.

if your database is fresh new, create your tables with `CHARACTER SET=utf8` option.

and add to your PHP scripts this call, right after db connect:

```
mysql_set_charset("<encoding>");
```

where `<encoding>` is the actual encoding of your pages

Comment: Col, Shrapnel - Actually, the real problem is with my iPhone App. It's passing the data via URL to my info.php script. This means, some special characters like "ç" and "&" are not being passed correctly. I think maybe that this cannot be fixed with my php script, but the app code. Right?

Comment: @BigMike it's hard to tell without an actual example of such "incorrectly passed character". But anything can be corrected with PHP script as well. Anything being passed via URL should be properly encoded, like PHP `urlencode()` function does.

Comment: ok, great. Thanks. I'll have a look at my objective-c code and make sure things are properly encoded.